# How to GPG encrypt file to different standard than default

Tags: encryption, gnupg

My GPG version 2.2.12 is initialised @ AES256. How can I encrypt files at a more secure RSA-4096?

Comment: Are you using this as an application, or calling it as a library from a program that you are writing? A question about the former would not fit on this site. In any case, like any legitimate tool, GPG won't encrypt data solely with RSA. It uses a hybrid scheme, and while it may be debatable, AES-256 can be considered the best cipher available for the symmetric portion. RSA would require a ridiculous key length to have strength comparable to AES-256. In any case, the RSA part of the hybrid encryption scheme will use the public key of the recipient, and that's what determines the key length.

Comment: I will stay with AES256 based on your reply. Many thanks.